# issues in stripe cli installation

Tags: stripe-payments, e-commerce, payment-gateway, visual-web-developer

hello friends is there any developer who can help me I am trying to install Stripe cli for my project but it is showing a virus in the file I extracted from a zip file and the antivirus is deleting that exe file Is Anyone who can tell me how I can install stripe cli in my system

I want to install stripe cli but it is not installing file I extracted from GitHub downloaded zip file is showing a virus and deleting that file

Comment: depending on what antivirus you're using, you can always mark a file as not being a virus/threat and then you can run it normally. As you can see, there's still an open [issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues/692) on stripe-cli's github but there's nothing really that can be done there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.